# How can I add search_index for RawHTMLBlock?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, wagtail

This FieldBlock don't have `get_searchable_content` property.

Is it possible to search in these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `RawHTMLBlock` does not make its content available for search, because it is typically used to insert non-text widgets such as maps and charts which aren't supported by a standard `RichTextBlock` - this would end up polluting the search index with irrelevant terms such as "script" that just happen to appear as HTML tags.

If you really want this content to be searchable, you can create a subclass of `RawHTMLBlock` that defines a `get_searchable_content` method, and use this new class in place of `RawHTMLBlock`. However, if you're regularly using `RawHTMLBlock` to hold meaningful searchable text, then that probably means your content isn't as well-structured and reusable as it could be - I'd recommend looking at other options such as `RichTextBlock` wherever possible.

Comment: I don’t have many such blocks like `RawHTMLBlock`, main is realy `RichTextBlock`, but some information is in `RawHTMLBlock` and I want to find it too. Ок, I'l use your advice, thanks for the reply.